# SPring MVC - Several Controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I am developing for learning purposes my very first "big" Spring MVC project. I am learning everything by myself (and of course, thanks to this amazing community).

What I am starting to wonder is... Is my design "correct/valid"? So far I am creating one `Controller` per View/Page specially because of the `ModelAttribute`s (attached to the method).

Is that fine? Should I start doing it in some other way? Are there "offical" patterns in this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, I assume you are creating a web project based on your use of ModelAttribute.  You want to follow the MVC (Model, View, Controller) convention.  The "Model" is the data you are manipulating.  This data should be retrieved via a service layer.  Then, your controller should call your service methods to get the data, making your controllers completely agnostic of your data.  This is nice because you are free to change your data structure, e.g. migrating from MySQL to MongoDB, without worrying about changing your controller, all you need to change is your service layer.  Also, this allows for controllers to use many different services in certain instances.  Your controller receives requests from the client, e.g. the website user's page requests, GET/POST requests, etc., and performs some action, usually fetching/updating data via the service layer, and then returns a view.  Each controller can take many requests, and can render many views.  It is good practice to break up controllers by function.  For example, if you had two different sections for your website, one for Admins, and one for Guests, then you may want to use one controller to process the Admin requests, and another to process the Guest requests.  Each of these controllers can handle all requests from Admins/Guests accordingly.  You may be a bit confused about controllers.  Each **method** in a controller is bound to a single request/view, but a controller may have many such methods.

As you are learning, I would suggest exploring some client-side mvc frameworks like AngularJS.  Angular allows very easy data binding and manipulation options, and makes it pretty easy to create RESTful web services.

Comment: Thanks for this clarifying answer! I will take a look at AngularJS as you suggest. On the other hand, I am actually wondering whether it is correct to use one controller for one single View. So far, I am doing it that way so I've got several `Controllers` with one (GET) or two methods (GET & POST).

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with using one controller per view, however if you add many views, you will have many controllers, which will begin to make the project hard to scale (and can quickly become a mess if you perform any authentication or authorization).  It is easier to manage the code if you break up the controllers by function, but there is nothing technically wrong with using one controller per view.